# Changing bar button appearance causes crash

Tags: iphone, ios, sharekit, uiappearance

I am customizing `MFMailComposeViewController`. For changing it's UI I detected the `UIBarButtonItem` and changing it's appearance using:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTitle:@""];
```

I am getting crashed in my other classes where I used `UIBarButtonItem` with text. I fixed those by using customView for the bar button. I am also using share kit in my app and now I am having crash in twitter login screen when keyboard appears with toolbar (In next/Previous and Done buttons).

1. Is there any way to avoid crashes in my app's other bar button items after I set appearance for a specific class?
2. Is there any way to assign customView to ShareKit's twitter's login screen's buttons?
3. Is there any way to remove those bar buttons if no for both above?

Thanks.

[image: If this can customize can we?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UIBarButtonItem` appearance proxy does not have a method for `setTitle`.

In the documentation you will find wich method are available for [Customizing Appearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007519-CH3-SW52)

Answer (score 0):

You can't customise the appearance of the `MFMailComposeViewController`.

From Apple's [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) on the class:

> "The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application."

Comment: You can use the Appearance proxy the change the look and feel of `MFMailComposeViewController` You cannot change any text but you can definitely change the color of the navigation bar and thing like that.

Comment: there is an app name WeHeartPics did the UI customization. We just want to change the look and feel of the composer and button's title to Done and Cancel with our custom fonts